# How to create a table correctly sequelize with typescript

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I'm trying to do so:

```
interface UserI {
    id?: number | null,
    name: string,
    password: string
}


@Table(
    {
        tableName: 'user',
        timestamps: true
    }
)
class User extends Model implements UserI{

    @AutoIncrement
    @PrimaryKey
    @Column(INTEGER)
    id!: number

    @AllowNull(false)
    @NotEmpty
    @Column(STRING)
    name!: string

    @AllowNull(false)
    @NotEmpty
    @Column(STRING)
    password!: string

}
```

But constantly getting an error: TypeError: Class constructor Model cannot be invoked without 'new';
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Model, Column, Table, AutoIncrement, PrimaryKey, NotEmpty, AllowNull } from "sequelize-typescript";

@Table(
    {
        tableName: 'user',
        timestamps: true
    }
)
export class User extends Model<User>{
    @AutoIncrement
    @PrimaryKey
    @Column
    id!: number

    @AllowNull(false)
    @NotEmpty
    @Column
    name!: string

    @AllowNull(false)
    @NotEmpty
    @Column
    password!: string
}
```

No need interface.